# Issue with my loop, want to terminate with correct choice (JAVA)

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String question = ("How many states are there in the United States of America?\n");
        question += "A. There are 48 states.\n";
        question += "B. There are 50 states.\n";
        question += "C. There are 52 states.\n";
        question += "D. There are 13 states.\n";
        question += "E. There are 26 states.\n";

    while (true) {
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        if (answer.equals("B")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");}
        switch (answer) 
            {
            //case "B":
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
                //break;
            case "A": 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose A, that is incorrect. Please try again");
                break;
            case "C":  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose C, that is incorrect. Please try again");
                break;
            case "D":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose D, that is incorrect.Please try again");
            break;
            case "E": 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose E, that is incorrect.Please try again");
            break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You made an invalid selection, please enter A,B,C,D, or E.");
                break;
            }


        }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to have the program stop asking the question once the correct answer is selected. If a wrong choice is selected, i want the question to come up until the user chooses the right answer and then have the program terminate. Right now i am getting the "default" statement come up after selecting the correct answer and it doesn't terminate.

Comment: Try adding a `break` statement after showing the "correct" dialog.  (Check your course notes to find out what `break` does.)

Comment: I compiled the code and it seemed to have the correct behavior, maybe restart your IDE and try again?  If you are wanting the program to terminate after the select answer is chosen I would have a boolean variable initialized to true and have that variable as the condition for the while loop and when the correct answer is chosen set that boolean to false.

Comment: You have a while(true) loop, which will go forever. You need to use the break statement to leave the loop, or change the loop to use a boolean variable that you can set to false when you want to leave.

Comment: should i get rid of my if statement, and include my right answer in the switch? If so, it works as intended, but doesnt terminate the loop.

Comment: Perhaps, but how would that help your problem? You need to worry about the loop, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the while(true) if you know that your program will terminate when the answer is B, and maybe do something like this.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String question = ("How many states are there in the United States of America?\n");
        question += "A. There are 48 states.\n";
        question += "B. There are 50 states.\n";
        question += "C. There are 52 states.\n";
        question += "D. There are 13 states.\n";
        question += "E. There are 26 states.\n";
        String answer = "";
        // This will work with 'B' and 'b' because your setting your answer to uppercase
        while (!answer.equals("B")) {
            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            answer = answer.toUpperCase();
            switch (answer) {
                case "B":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
                    break;
                case "A":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose A, that is incorrect. Please try again");
                    break;
                case "C":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose C, that is incorrect. Please try again");
                    break;
                case "D":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose D, that is incorrect.Please try again");
                    break;
                case "E":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose E, that is incorrect.Please try again");
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You made an invalid selection, please enter A,B,C,D, or E.");
                    break;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

You are probably getting the default statement because of the commented B case line.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it putting the switch statement inside an else block. I prefer to keep all the checking inside the switch and use a control variable:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String question = ("How many states are there in the United States of America?\n");
        question += "A. There are 48 states.\n";
        question += "B. There are 50 states.\n";
        question += "C. There are 52 states.\n";
        question += "D. There are 13 states.\n";
        question += "E. There are 26 states.\n";

        boolean rightAnswer = false; 

        while (rightAnswer != true) {
            String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            answer = answer.toUpperCase();

            switch (answer) {
                case "B":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Correct!");
                    rightAnswer = true;
                    break;
                case "A": 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose A, that is incorrect. Please try again");
                    break;
                case "C":  
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose C, that is incorrect. Please try again");
                    break;
                case "D":
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose D, that is incorrect.Please try again");
                break;
                case "E": 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose E, that is incorrect.Please try again");
                break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You made an invalid selection, please enter A,B,C,D, or E.");
                    break;
                }       

        }
}
```